# Allow socket connection in Solaris

Tags: solaris, port, socket

I have 2 solaris machines and I have an application that opens a socket via port 8556, but for some reason the connection keeps getting refused.

When I run a netstat command on the second server (serverb):

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8556
127.0.0.1.8556             *.*                0      0 128000      0 LISTEN
```

Which seems to indicate the port is open, I can even telnet to the localhost:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8556
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
```

But when I try to telnet from the first machine, the connection fails:

```
bash-3.00# telnet serverb 8556
Trying 5.5.112.112...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I can ssh successfully from servera to serverb, but the socket connection is refused. I have tried the hostname and the ip address, but no luck. Also i can telnet to port 22 and and 23 from servera to serverb, and these ports appear to be open, its just a problem with port 8556.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listening socket is bound to `127.0.0.1`, as your `netstat` output shows. It is not bound to `5.5.112.112` or `0.0.0.0` (which acts as a wildcard).

Comment: I see, would the application itself (how the socket reading / writing is coded) need to be updated to fix this problem? Or is it a configuration on the server?

Comment: Most likely, it's the way the application is configured. But it could be the application is hard-coded to bind to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, your info helped me find that a single IP address was specified inside the function that initialized the socket. I found that I could update this function to "any" IP. I restarted the app, ran the netstat command and saw that it was no longer bound to 127.0.0.1, but to *. Thanks so much! Been stuck on this all day